# Running a bash script (with some npm commands in it) in Ubuntu by double-clicking on the bash-file runs into `npm: command not found` error

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, ubuntu, npm

I am currently trying to set up my system so I can run my bash file (`startWebApp.bash`) on Ubuntu by double-clicking on it. Unfortunately, that is not working, but when I run the script in the terminal with `./startWebApp.bash` it works fine.
The underlying problem seems to be that the `$PATH` variable is different when running the script by double-clicking on the file. The `$PATH` variable when I run the file in my Terminal is:

```
/home/magonba/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

While when I run the file by double-clicking on it, `$PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Why is there a difference and how can I change that?

### Reproduction steps:

1. Create the file `startWebApp.bash` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service postgresql restart
cd /home/my/project/folder/nodejsapp
npm start &
cd /home/my/project/folder/vuejsapp
npm run serve &
```

2. I set in the File Manager under `Preferences` -> `Behavior` -> `Executable Text Files` to `Ask what to do` (in order to be able to start the application by double-clicking on it).
3. When I double-click on the file, Ubuntu offers me the options: `Run in Terminal`, `Display`, `Cancel` and `Run`
4. I choose `Run in Terminal` (because I need to provide a password since I am using a sudo command)
5. Runs into the error(s):

```
/home/my/project/folder/nodejsapp/startWebApp.bash: line 6: npm: command not found
/home/my/project/folder/vuejsapp/startWebApp.bash: line 8: npm: command not found
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you got here is, that nvm is integrated in you .bashrc. But when you run your bash file from the GUI, your bashrc will be ignored, and a very minimal bash shell is started. You can fix this in multiple ways.

1. Install npm to a system installation path (e.g. with apt)
2. Change your `$PATH` in the script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   PATH="/home/magonba/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin:$PATH"
   sudo service postgresql restart
   cd /home/my/project/folder/nodejsapp
   npm start &
   cd /home/my/project/folder/vuejsapp
   npm run serve &
   ```
3. Every time you call npm, give the full path

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo service postgresql restart
   cd /home/my/project/folder/nodejsapp
   /home/magonba/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/npm start &
   cd /home/my/project/folder/vuejsapp
   /home/magonba/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/npm run serve &
   ```
4. Include your .bashrc in your script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   . /home/magonba/.bashrc
   sudo service postgresql restart
   cd /home/my/project/folder/nodejsapp
   npm start &
   cd /home/my/project/folder/vuejsapp
   npm run serve &
   ```

Please note.
If you go for solution 2 or 3, every time you change your npm version via nvm, you will have to change your script accordingly.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer! I tried nr. 4, but unfortunately it runs into the same error (`npm: command not found`). Any ideas why? Nr. 2 and 3 are less convenient since I will have to change the script when I change my npm versions, as you said. I guess I will have to go with nr. 1...

Comment: As a very long time Linux & UNIX user, I advise you to go with Nr. 1 or Nr. 2. Apt normally sets up a default version/path. Some ways around the version problem: don't worry about version changes unless they are actually important (v15 might be better than v14, but is the difference between v14.1 and v14.1.1 actually important?); use an environment variable to indicate the version to your script; soft link the desired version to a standard location and reference node via the soft link.